# C# How to check is there any value before converting ToString()

Tags: c#, casting, textbox, dataset

I have a dataset of values, which I need to put into a textbox. However, there are some `decimal` and `double` type values in my dataset, so I need to cast them `toString()`. Furthermore, sometimes the dataset values are empty, so before casting `toString()` I need to check whether there is actually a value there or not.
This is sample line:

I need code that does something like this...

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<decimal>("IndexPrethodni") !=null or something){
    Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<decimal>("IndexPrethodni"));
}
```

I known decimal is not a nullable type. Is there any easy solution to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for DBNull

if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field("IndexPrethodni") != DBNull.Value) {
   //convert to string
}

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd wrap it like so:

```
        var col = ds.Tables[0].Columns["IndexPrethodni"];
        var row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        if (!row.IsNull(col))
        {
            string s = row[col].ToString();
            ...
        }
```

(the "via a column object" is the most direct (= fastest) indexer)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IndexPrethodni"] != DBNull.Value)
```

You can also check the value using Convert.IsDBNull().

Answer (score 2):

I normally use a method such like:

```
public T GetValue<T>(object source)
{
  if (Convert.IsDBNull(source))
    return default(T);

  return (T)source;
}
```

E.g.

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  if (reader.Read())
  {
    return GetValue<string>(reader["SomeColumn"]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TO use Convert.ToString you need not to check for null value, because if there will null then also it will not give any error and return blank..

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value isnt DBNull, so something like this would work

```
object columnValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<decimal>("IndexPrethodni");
if (object != System.DBNull.Value) Convert.ToString(columnValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the nullable type to check for a value?

```
if( ds.Tables[ 0 ].Rows[ 0 ].Field<decimal?>( "IndexPrethodni" ).HasValue )
{
   Convert.ToString( ds.Tables[ 0 ].Rows[ 0 ].Field<decimal>( "IndexPrethodni" ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we are checking for decimal value is null or not before converting to other type

```
decimal? d;
if (!d.HasValue)
{
//d is null 
}
```